# Panda Pop has stopped working

Tags: android

Playing Panda Pop. I made several purchases for coins etc. Now when trying to open the game I get the message Panda Pop has stopped working. Is there something I can try to resolve this? I'm playing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab3. If this can't be fixed is there a way to transfer the purchased items? If this isn't the place to ask about this please point me in the right direction

Comment: This site is for programming related questions and answers not getting support with Android. Please look for support elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem for the longest.  Finally figured out a solution to the problem I had.  I was also able to continue from the last level played. Try downloading an APK Installer package for Android then restart your phone.  Let me know if this worked for you. Good luck.